# Issues with setValue() function in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script for **Google Sheets** and the following command is giving me issues:

```
cell.setValue("=IF(AND(D18>0,OR((month(D4)>1),(day(D4)>'Spreadsheet info'!F10),(AND(month(today()),C4=0)))),"Y",)");
```

If I remove the quotations for `Y`, then the issue goes away. I am pretty sure it is a quotation issue but I cannot figure out how to make the script work.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setFormula instead of setValue

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! The command setFormula, or even setValue for that matter doesn't work well with quotations within a quotations. So to fix the problem I was having, I needed to write the letter Y this way \"Y\". Like this :

cell.setValue("=IF(AND(D18>0,OR((month(D4)>1),(day(D4)>'Spreadsheet info'!F10),(AND(month(today()),C4=0)))),**\"Y\"**,)");

Comment: The example provided use setValue instead of setFormula. setFormula should be used for adding a formula to a cell.